# how do I make a constructor that duplicate the original constructor including all of the node informations?

Tags: java

says this is the constructor of the `TableDeque` class (implements `Deque`), and it has many more nodes in the class.

```
public TableDeque() {
    head = new Node<Customer>(null);
    tail = new Node<Customer>(null);
    head.join(tail);
    size = 0;
    this.setImage("table");
}
```

I want to make a duplicated `TableDeque`, so I declared another constructor that takes `TableDeque` as a parameter

```
public TableDeque (TableDeque copy) {
    this();
    // copy properties from the source TableDeque to the new instance
}
```

Thus, `TableDeque(this)` has to return duplicates original with all of the node information, but I have no idea how to do that.

I have pondered and tried to do this by myself, but I still stuck at this :( please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a shallow copy (That is changes to `head` or `tail` object after reflected in both places) , just set the fields in `copy` object to `this` , like -

```
public TableDeque (TableDeque copy)
{
    // copy properties from the source TableDeque to the new instance
    this.head = copy.getHead(); //this function returns the `head` property of TableDeque class
    this.tail = copy.getTail(); //this function returns the `tail` property of TableDeque class
    head.join(tail);
    this.size = copy.getSize();  //this function returns the `size` property of TableDeque class
    this.setImage(copy.getImage()); //this function returns the `image` property of TableDeque class

}
```

I would say it is always advised to keep member variabes in java private and expose getters and setters for them.

To create a deep copy (changes to `head` and `tail` are not reflected) , -

```
public TableDeque (TableDeque copy)
{
    // copy properties from the source TableDeque to the new instance
    this.head = new Node(copy.getHead()); 
    this.tail = new Node(copy.getTail()); 
    head.join(tail);
    this.size = copy.getSize();  
    this.setImage(copy.getImage());

}
```

Then you will need to create a copy constructors for `Node` class as well.

Answer (score 2):

Create a copy constructor for your Node class, then:

```
public TableDeque (TableDeque copy) {
    head = new Node(copy.head);
    tail = new Node(copy.tail);
    size = copy.size;
    setImage(copy.image);
}
```

You'll have to guard against an infinite loop in your Node copy constructor if there's a closed loop (use a Set to keep tracking nodes visited).